# What is the difference between the inflaters

Tags: android, layout-inflater

What is the difference between doing

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

and `inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the difference between the inflaters

Difference is that in second example (via static method), you don't need to cast Object to `LayoutInflater` because it returns directly LayoutInflater instance.

First case returns generally Object that you have to explicitly cast to `LayoutInflater`. But result of both methods is new instance of `LayoutInflater`

Is up to you which method you'll pick up. I usually use `LayoutInflater.from();` method and never have problems. I don't need to cast from Object and it'll make a trick.

As @CommonsWare mentioned, you can also call

```
getLayoutInflater()
```

If you are in `Activity` class (it's method of Activity). But when you are not in Activity you need to have `Context` variable and then you can call (for example from ListAdapter):

```
((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
```

But i think when you are not in Activity it's much easier and efficient to call `LayoutInflater.from();` instead of approaches above.

Comment: And even easier is just to call `getLayoutInflater()` on your `Activity`.

Comment: its not from an activity, but rather a listview adapter

Comment: @CommonsWare but you are not always in Activity but i agree with you its correct but result of all mentioned approaches is same so how i said, it depends only on developer which way he will choose.

Comment: @Sajmon: "but you are not always in Activity" -- true, though the OP is, based on the question.